# Difficulty in plotting the polynomial function

Tags: plotting

I have a polynomial function which is in x, I am trying to plot this out but could not able to plot. how to do this

```
 P = -4.7199*10^1684 - 5.7120*10^1665/x^4 + 2.7526*10^1675/x^2 + 
       3.3229*10^1693 x^2 - 8.1287*10^1701 x^4 + 7.6220*10^1709 x^6 - 
       2.2376*10^1717 x^8 + 1.0269*10^1724 x^10;
    Plot[P, {x, 0, 10000000}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: It is best to Normalize the polynomial to avoid crazy numerical issues in such cases. Try plotting P/10^1684 instead.

Comment: Try `LogPlot[P, {x, 0, 10000000}]` or `LogLogPlot[P, {x, 0, 10000000}]`?

Comment: Using the online free cloud `P = -4.7199*10^1684 - 5.7120*10^1665/x^4 + 2.7526*10^1675/x^2 +3.3229*10^1693 x^2 - 8.1287*10^1701 x^4 + 7.6220*10^1709 x^6 -2.2376*10^1717 x^8 + 1.0269*10^1724 x^10;
ListPlot[Table[{x,P/10^1500}, {x, 1, 10^7, 10^5}],Joined->True]` displays the curve. Change 1500 to 1490 displays a blank space without error. Change 1500 to 1480 and it displays `Value of Option PlotRange->{{0,9.9*10^6}...is not All, Full, Automatic...` That appears to be "unexpected behavior." Would anyone with a contact politely report that and see if that might get "enhanced" someday? Thanks